# Mybatis: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Statement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, mybatis

when I use Mybatis execute query sql for oracle database, it sometimes throw the exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException:
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Statement
### The error may exist in com/mapper/TestMapper.xml
### The error may involve com.mapper.TestMapper.getList
### The error occurred while handling results
### SQL: SELECT *    FROM person_view
```

the xml config for the query:

```
<select id="getList" resultType="com.domain.TestBean" parameterType="map">  
select * from person_view where rownum < #{limit}
</select>
```

when the query time > 60s, it will throw the exception, however I can't find any query time limit in my mybatis configuration and connection pool configuration. Any ideas, thanks in advance.

Comment: Java code that executes the query? Are you closing the statement as the exception states somewhere in the code? Is there a catch block that does that for queries that time out?

Comment: mybatis will take care of it, the query works fine if the execute time < 60s.